# Eclipse : Cursor beyond end of line - possible?

Tags: eclipse

does anyone know if it's possible in Eclipse to set 'Cursor beyond end-of-line' , so the cursor always stays on the same horizontal position, even when the line is not long enough for that?

Almost every editor I know of has this option  (Borland Delphi, Microsoft Visual Studio and others).

Answer (score 1):

afaik this feature is not available in eclipse yet (I would expect it to be in `Window/Preferences.../General/Editors/Text Editors`)

But I found a feature request for this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21000

You could try to find a plugin-project for this, maybe some other users have implemented that feature already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but that did not worked for me.

What I did is:

- I opened a new pydev module.
- Pressed ctrl+alt+enter and options for python console showed up
- I chose the python console (second option)
- And pressed the PIN CONSOLE icon to pin it forever.

I didnt have ipython installed but it works perfectly fine no probs at all.